# The category of Chow correspondences

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

In Marc Levine, *Six Lectures on Motives*, in the first chapter, the author defines the so-called the category of Chow correspondences. I suffer from certain technical details related to algebraic cycles and correspondences. In the following, $k$ is a field and all schemes are $k$-schemes.

- Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme and $D$ be an its Cartier divisor He claims that we can extend by linear to define an operation $D\cdot\square: z_n(X)_D \to z_{n-1}(D)$ where $z_n(X)_D$ is the free abelian group generated by integral closed subschemes $Z$ of dimension $n$ which is not contained in $D$ and $z_r$ is simply group of $r$-dimensional algebraic cycles, and $D.Z = \sum m_i Z_i$ where $Z_i$'s are irreducible components of $D \times_X Z$, $m_i$'s are certain integers. My question is why do we need the hypothesis $Z \nsubseteq D$ to make the operator $D \cdot \square$ well-defined.
- If $X, Y$ and $Z$ are smooth projective $k$-schemes then we can compose elements in Chow groups (they are also called correspondeces) by the following formula $$\beta \circ \alpha = p_{XZ*}(p_{XY}^*(\alpha) \cdot p_{YZ}^*(\beta))$$ where $\alpha \in CH_{\mathrm{dim}(X)}(X \times Y), \beta \in CH_{\mathrm{dim}(Y)}(Y \times Z)$, $p_{XY}^*,p_{YZ}^*$ are pull-back operators of $$p_{XY}:X \times Y \times Z \to X \times Z, \ p_{YZ}: X \times Y \times X \times Z$$ and $p_{XZ*}$ is push-forward operator of $p_{XZ}:X \times Y \times Z \to X \times Z$. All of $p_{AB}$ defined in the obvious way; being projective make them well-defined. My question is: how can I think about correspondences intuitively? I did search somewhere else but it does not help me at all and correspondences are notoriously abstract that I do not even know how to prove this composition law is associative.

Comment: 1: you need this to get the dimension right. Intersecting $D$ with something contained in $D$ doesn't drop the dimension and therefore can't take $n$-cycles to $n-1$ cycles like the map is written to. 2: A correspondence is a subvariety of $X\times Y$ and can be thought of as a multi-valued function.

Comment: @KReiser, 1) okay, but do you have any detailed reference for this decrease of dimension? 2) I know people often say to think a correspondence as a multi-valued function but it would be better if you could provide a concrete example. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: 1. Read any introductory algebraic geometry book. (If you're trying to study motives and don't know how dimension works for intersections in algebraic geometry, this is a serious problem and you need to remedy this before moving on.) 2. Sure, think about $V(x-y^2)\subset\Bbb A^1\times\Bbb A^1$. This is the square root.

Comment: @KReiser 1) I know that any AG book contains dimension stuff but I hope there is a precise proposition so that I could refer directly. 2) For me I do not think the situation is that simple to think about correspondences. In fact, if one considers a Weil cohomology then we demand the existence of a cycle map from Chow groups to this cohomology such that the fiber product is compatible with graded structure of the cohomology; therefore, correspondences determine morphisms between cohomology, and to construct Chow motives, it is natural to enlarge the class of usual morphisms to correspondences.

Comment: And to prove the law is associative is indeed not a simple task.

Comment: 1: It is enough to work affine-locally on $X$ where $D$ is effective and cut out by a single equation $f$. The assumption that $Z\not\subset D$ implies that $f$ restricts to something nonzero in the coordinate algebra of $Z$, and then by Krull's height theorem all irreducible components of the vanishing locus of $f$ on $Z$ are codimension one. All results necessary to prove this are in Hartshorne chapter I section 1. 2: Yes, it's complicated, but you didn't ask for help proving associativity, you asked for help thinking about things intuitively. I find it's best to start simple for that.

Comment: @KReiser :P I thought my last sentence is also considered as a question. Thank you!